# public school teaching grades 7-12 considered "academic"?

Tags: discussion

There are several questions with with the words "high school" and teaching on academia. 
Can a public school teacher be considered an "academician"? I haven't found any other stackexchange site that is likely to allow for questions about teaching, much less at the secondary level. Has anyone found another site that allow such questions?

Comment: I have voted to close since the question is essentially: I know this isn't the correct site for me, but where should I go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to Academia.SE, this site is about those involved in higher education (postgrad, research etc).  There is a Proposal in Area51 for [Education](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50826/education).

Comment: I see. That proposal has some time ahead before it ever enters Beta. Academia is still in beta. If we merged the two, would the scope be so general that the number of users.  questions , tags get out of hand are too difficult to manage? Or possibly allow so many topics that it is hard to define the intent and topics which reflect it?

Comment: @user6089 I seriously doubt that they would be merged.  There is a separate Undergraduates proposal also, as that is also off topic here.  This site is solely for those involved in higher education.

Comment: @user6089: It would not make sense to include high school, college, and postgraduate education in a single board. The sets are too disjoint to coexist logically.

Comment: See https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/just-how-high-is-higher-education

Answer (score 2):

If your field is in mathematics education, you might want to look at [The Mathematics Teaching Community](https://mathematicsteachingcommunity.math.uga.edu/).  (But as of now, there is not much activity there.)

Answer (score 2):

Although high school teaching is not on topic at this site, I completely agree that it could be considered "academic" under some interpretations of the word.  "Academia" is used here as a single-word summary for the site's topic, and unfortunately it's impossible to find a single word that perfectly fits.  No disrespect is meant towards high school teaching, and no implication that it's not really academic.  It's just not a particularly natural match for the sort of grad student/professor questions this site is intended for.